# Custom URL for Azure AD B2C signup and signin pages

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, custom-domain

I'm working on integrating Azure Active directory B2C for sign-up and sign-in process. By default, when a user clicks the login button, it has to redirect the user to a different domain (*microsoftonline.com*) such that the URL for sign-up and sign-in page is in the following format:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.......

However, I think this is a bad user experience for users redirecting them to other domain for signing in.
So I'd like to use my own domain (e.g. example.com) so that the URL should be like below.

https://login.example.com/te/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.......

I've done some research on Azure documentation and found out that it does not currently support setting up the custom URL for sign-up and sign-in page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

However, the case study from Azure B2C mentioned that the Real Madrid offical home page also uses Azure AD B2C for user management (https://customers.microsoft.com/en-ca/story/real-madrid). 
However, the domain in the URL for sign-in page is not *microsoftonline.com* but their own domain, *realmadrid.com*, like below

https://pro.login.realmadrid.com/rmglndpdaadfans.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?p=B2C_1_SignInSignUpWeb&client_id=8a943960-87f9-4e22-bc2a-40099d584719&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.realmadrid.com%2Fcs%2FSatellite%3Fpagename%3DRealMadridResponsive%2FPage%2FRM_IDPRespuesta&resource=https%3A%2F%2Frmglndpdaadfans.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapi&response_mode=fragment&response_type=token+id_token&scope=openid&nonce=defaultNonce&idpmode=0&lang=en&_ga=2.211460117.1443111640.1554916216-543571806.1554916216

I've checked the following pages but none of them helped..

1. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/B2C-with-custom-login-URL/td-p/44040
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

So how can I achieve this as Real Madrid home page did with Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you are able to use [the `your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com` domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) (recommended) or the `login.microsoftonline.com` domain, latter of which is being deprecated.

Work for [support of customer-owned domains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains) has been started.

Comment: but how the Real Madrid site could achieve that?
their sign-in page's URL starts with their own domain like below

https://pro.login.realmadrid.com/rmglndpdaadfans.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authoriz........

Not sure if there's another way of going around this..

Comment: Hi @androisojavaswift They must be special. :)

Comment: Hi @androisojavaswift. Did the above answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

The capability to use a custom domain for your B2C tenant is now available in public preview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: Is this really the solution given that it's mandatory to go through costly Azure Front Door?