# How to change default URL for Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

Just created a dotnet core MVC web application in Visual Studio 2019.

Added Work and School accounts (Azure AD) for authentication.

When browsing to the app it takes to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ for authentication:

Can this domain be customized? Like show login.mycompany.com (vanity URL) in the browser address bar?

Comment: [It does not appear to be possible at the moment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-i-use-my-own-urls-on-my-sign-up-and-sign-in-pages-that-are-served-by-azure-ad-b2c-for-instance-can-i-change-the-url-from-contosob2clogincom-to-logincontosocom).

Comment: For Azure AD B2C there is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621065/custom-url-for-azure-ad-b2c-signup-and-signin-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to customized the login URL currently.

Although the links provided by @poke and @Sergey is for Azure AD B2C, the answer is the same.

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints), the registered apps have to communicate with Microsoft identity platform by sending requests to the endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```